# How to set a background image in view using Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

hi
     I want to set a background image into my view which has several subview .

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this is to:

1. Add a UIImageView as a sibling to your subviews that is the size of the main view, and apply your Image to this view.
2. All sibling views set the Background color to have an alpha of 0. This will make the view transparent, but not affect any elements they contain.